Compilation error: Input index file not found, and biber failed
I am trying to compile a LaTeX document using a Windows batch file that includes creating an index and glossary. However, I encounter the following error messages:
Compiling test.tex...
Input index file test.idx not found.
Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]
pdflatex: major issue: So far, you have not checked for updates as a MiKTeX user.
biber: major issue: So far, you have not checked for updates as a MiKTeX user.
Error: biber failed.

Here is the batch file I am using:
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set OUTDIR=build
set DOC=test
set DOCFILE=%DOC%
set DOC_EXT=%DOC%.tex

if not exist %DOC_EXT% (
    echo Error: %DOC_EXT% not found.
    exit /b 1
)

if exist %OUTDIR% rmdir /s /q %OUTDIR%
if not exist %OUTDIR% mkdir %OUTDIR%

echo Compiling %DOC_EXT%...

CALL :pdflatex
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 (
    echo Error: pdflatex failed.
    exit /b 1
)

CALL :biber
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 (
    echo Error: biber failed.
    exit /b 1
)

CALL :makeindex
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 (
    echo Error: makeindex failed.
    exit /b 1
)

CALL :makeglossaries
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 (
    echo Error: makeglossaries failed.
    exit /b 1
)

CALL :pdflatex
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 (
    echo Error: pdflatex failed.
    exit /b 1
)

CALL :pdflatex
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 (
    echo Error: pdflatex failed.
    exit /b 1
)

CALL :cleanup

echo Compilation completed successfully.
exit /b 0

:: Functions

:pdflatex
pdflatex -file-line-error -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=%OUTDIR% %DOC_EXT% > %OUTDIR%\pdflatex.log
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%

:biber
biber.exe --output_directory %OUTDIR% %DOC% > %OUTDIR%\biber.log
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%

:makeindex
makeindex %OUTDIR%\%DOC%.idx > %OUTDIR%\makeindex.log
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%

:makeglossaries
makeglossaries -d %OUTDIR% %DOC% > %OUTDIR%\makeglossaries.log
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%

:cleanup
del /s /q %OUTDIR%\*.aux %OUTDIR%\*.bbl %OUTDIR%\*.blg %OUTDIR%\*.toc %OUTDIR%\*.out %OUTDIR%\*.bcf %OUTDIR%\*-blx.bib %OUTDIR%\*.acn %OUTDIR%\*.acr %OUTDIR%\*.alg %OUTDIR%\*.glg %OUTDIR%\*.gls %OUTDIR%\*.ist
exit /b 0

endlocal

And the minimal working example (MWE) of the LaTeX document:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{glossaries} % Load the glossaries package

\makeglossaries % Initialize the glossaries system
\makeindex

\begin{document}
This is some text with an \index{important term} that should appear in the index.

\printindex
\end{document}

The error messages suggest that:

The test.idx file is not found when running makeindex.
There is an issue with MiKTeX not being updated when running pdflatex and biber.

What could be causing these issues, and how can I resolve them to compile the document with the index and glossary successfully?

For your sanity: it is always better to not use output directories

Dear @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, we have had this discussion on this platform multiple times. And I believe our views on the topic are incompatible, and we should not bother convincing one another. Otherwise, thanks for your comment and attention.

well you could at least take @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz's hint and check if it works when you don't use an output directory. If yes you would know what is causing the issue.

@UlrikeFischer, I would rather not pursue that option because I know I am unable to deal with the messy root folder.

sure, but if you know that this is the problem you could start to investigate why makeindex doesn't find the file. Or consider more sane options, like copying the tex-document into the build folder and compiling there.

oh and regarding the miktex messages: do what it tells you and check in the miktex console (user and admin mode!) for updates.

@UlrikeFischer, I tried that to no avail. I am hoping to resolve the issue from the command line using initexmf and/or mpm. This tends to happen every once in a while;e and I don't understand what causes this issue!

on the command line you can use miktex packages check-update
or miktex --admin packages check-update and other options, see https://docs.miktex.org/manual/miktex-packages.html

@UlrikeFischer I did not know about this command line tool. Thanks. How can I install the updates as well?

you could read the documentation I linked too.

@UlrikeFischer fair enough. My bad. Apologies. Will check the documentation.

In an attempt to solve this issue, I tried @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz 's suggestion to compile everything into the root folder, but it did not solve the issue. I even tried latexmk and texify to no avail, and my new post was also not appreciated, facing quite some scrutiny!


The error occurs because the package imakeindex calls makeindex during the compilation of the document by pdflatex.  That call knows nothing about the output directory; it only looks for text.idx in the current directory.
There's an explicit (and correct) invocation of makeindex in the batch file, so there's no need for the automatic invocation by the package.  You should turn off the automatic invocation of makeindex by giving the imakeidx package its noautomatic option:
\usepackage[noautomatic]{imakeidx}


Your document doesn't have a bibliography, so biber should not be invoked; it will always fail because there's no test.bcf file.

In any case the command line to biber is misspelled.  It should be
biber.exe --output-directory %OUTDIR% %DOC% > %OUTDIR%\biber.log  


When debugging a batch file, I would strongly recommend against using echo off.  I would also recommend against redirecting output to a file.  Those both make it much harder to see what is going wrong.  Once the batch file is debugged, you can restore those settings.


